# Can java.awt.Component.getBounds() be null?

Tags: java, awt

I cannot find the answer in specs or by searching for it. Has anybody seen this being null? Can I use properties without checking for null?

Comment: As far as I know, NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the current Oracle / OpenJDK implementation of AWT, then `Component.getBounds()` cannot return null because it always creates a new `Rectangle` object.  The source code is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/awt/Component.java#Component.getBounds%28%29).

None of the standard AWT classes override the methods (as far as I can see).

In theory, someone could subclass an AWT component class and override `getBounds()` to return `null`, but that would be ... perverse.

---

My advice would be to assume it is non-null, and treat any (hypothetical) NPEs as bugs.

---

<sup>I do not subscribe to the theory that you should guard against NPEs in every possible place.  It is better to let them happen and fix them.  The flip side to that is that you should only allow a state value to be `null` if this has a definite meaning.  Avoid situations where things can be null as an "optimization", or because you forgot to initialize them. And write good unit tests so that your mistakes are picked up early.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

getBounds() returns a Rectangle object. As far as I can tell, when you create a Component, a Rectangle object is created, so this method will not return null.

This is because when you create a Component, either a button, checkbox, scrollbar, etc., such objects will always have a boundary in the form of a Rectangle object.